# No se me actualizan los cambios en GridLayout java android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, update, css-grid-layout

Tengo una actividad con GridLayout et varios botones  .A hacer clic en un botón , se vuelve  invisible para siempre.
Hasta aquí todos bien pero el problema surje cuando cierro la actividad y volvo a abrir, no me aparece los cambios.
parece que se me recyclar la vista sin
recycleView.
Mi actividad tiene una conexión directa con el archvivo xml.
Mi GridLayout esta dentro de un NestedScrollView.
Cada botón esta  dentro de un CardView.
El Lenguaje de programación :java
Plataforma:android studio

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:

¿cómo guardar los cambios de forma permanente?

Mi código xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.SiegeActivityok">


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:columnCount="6"
                app:orientation="vertical"
                app:rowCount="15">

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button2"
                        android:layout_width="54dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0.5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="0.5dp"
                        android:backgroundTint="#7F85FD"
                        android:text="56"
                        android:textColor="@color/noir_fonce"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgV19"
                        android:layout_width="55dp"
                        android:layout_height="41dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/escalier" />
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button4"
                        android:layout_width="54dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0.5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="0.5dp"
                        android:backgroundTint="#7F85FD"
                        android:text="64"
                        android:textColor="@color/noir_fonce"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button5"
                        android:layout_width="54dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0.5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="0.5dp"
                        android:backgroundTint="#7F85FD"
                        android:text="70"
                        android:textColor="@color/noir_fonce"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


            </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnValidezSiege"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/Validez" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textSetSelection"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:text="@string/Selection"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>





    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

El código de actividad Main:

```
public class SiegeActivityok extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener/*OnClickAction */{

    GridLayout gridLayout;

    TextView textPrix,textView,textView2,textSetSelection;
    Button btnValidezSiege;

    Button button2;
    Button button3;
    Button button4;
   
    NestedScrollView nestedScrollView;

   

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_siege_activityok);

        gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);

        textSetSelection = findViewById(R.id.textSetSelection);
        textPrix = findViewById(R.id.textPrix);
        nestedScrollView = findViewById(R.id.nestedScrollView);

        btnValidezSiege = findViewById(R.id.btnValidezSiege);
        textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        //textV = findViewById(R.id.textV);


        btnValidezSiege.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(SiegeActivityok.this, MonaiePayeActivity.class);



                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });

        button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button5 = findViewById(R.id.button5);
       
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        button4.setOnClickListener(this);
     }
       
      

     

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       
           
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button4) {

            button3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return;
        }


    }

 
}
```

Comment: No entiendo bien que sucede lo de que reinicias la app, pero en tal caso para mantener algo oculto "para siempre" deberías usar SQLite, Room para almacenar un valor y si este valor es 0 se oculta, si es 1 se muestra.

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo es una app de viaje ,los butones representan los asientos.A seleccionar tiene que estar invisible para no volver a ser seleccionados.

Comment: Entonces vas a necesitar una BD online, como MySQL o usar Firebase

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo se puede tener un codigo de ejemplo ? se puede optar por SharedPreference? gracias

Comment: Al ser una App de viajes, una Preference solo te va a servir para el dispositivo actual que lo vea pero este cambio no se va a ver reflejado en otros teléfonos ya que la Preference solo afecta al dispositivo local. Lo mismo sucedería con SQLite.

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo que opción me aconsejas?

Comment: No te puedo aconsejar nada porque desconozco tu modelo de negocio pero te recomiendo investigar sobre Firebase y MySQL para que puedas orientarte y ver cual te favorece

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo vale gracias.

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo estaba intentando con un" SystemClock.sleep(10000000)" pero solo consigue programar el tiempo de espera antes del cambio¿Hay una manera de programar la duración para mantener  este cambio? con que me dura solo 24h me basta.

Comment: Disculpa pero no entendí nada de lo que quisiste decir

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo fijar el tiempo de duración del cambio pero se destruye igualmente. que desastrosa soy.

Comment: A ver, para que un cambio persista debes almacenar el valor en algún lado. Si este cambio solo se va a ver en un dispositivo, usarías Room, SQLite, etc. Si este cambio debe afectar a muchos telénofos, debes usar Firebase, MySQL+php, etc. El tiempo de duración que quieres aplicar no va a funcionar porque no lo estas guardando en ningún lado